# Submenu refuses to open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm trying to make a left side navigation bar where by-default categories are listed and while clicking on a category, the subcategories are shown under it (in sort expanding sub-menu). I'm working in `Django` and relevant portions of my code are below. When I include the `JS` code, none of the links on the page work and when I exclude it, all the subcategories for all categories are shown by-default. I need only categories to be shown by default and while clicking on any, the respective subcategories be shown. What I'm missing here?

JS CODE: at the bottom of the page, loaded after the footer:

```
{% block theme_script %}
<script src="{% static " pinax/js/theme.js " %}"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".nav-collapse88").hide();
    $(".nav-collapse89 a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".nav-collapse88", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
    });
  })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

My HTML:
My CATEGORYINDEX.HTML TEMPLATE:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n pybb_tags forumindexlistbycat %}

{% catindexlist as catindexlisted %}

{% block body %}
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 body-container leftsidenavigator" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 leftsidenavigator-inner" style="padding:0px;">
        <h2><center>Categories</center></h2>
            <ul class="catindexlist catlistcat nav-collapse89">
                {% for category in catindexlisted %}
                    <div class="catindexlistitem">
                        <li class="category-name" style="font-weight:600;padding-right:20px;"><a href="">{{category.name}}</a></li></div>
                <div class="nav-collapse88">
                    <ul style="padding:0px;">
                    {% for forum in category|forumindexlistbycat %}
                        <div class="catlistforum"><li style="padding-right:10px;"><a href="{{ forum.get_absolute_url }}">{{forum.name}}</a></li></div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

MY SITE_BASE.HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="border-right:solid;text-align:right;height:99%;padding:0 0 0 0px;" id="sidebar"> {% include "categoryindex.html" %} </div>
```

All who answer will win a magical Pony! Thanks,

Comment: Is this what you want? [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/td6yL2q8)

Comment: Almost. This code currently, expands all sub-menus when I click on any category. I need it to expand only the category which was clicked.

Comment: You should try to debug and see what you get in `$(".nav-collapse88", $(this).parent())` - my guess is this query returns empty list for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the concept of `parent` `siblings` you can do that as:

### Code Snippet

```js
 $(function() {
   $(".category-name a").parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').hide();
   $(".category-name a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".category-name a").parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').slideUp();
     if(!($(this).parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').is(":visible"))){
       $(this).parent('li').parent('div').siblings('div').slideToggle();
     }
   });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="catindexlist catlistcat nav-collapse89">
  {% for category in catindexlisted %}
  <div class="catindexlistitem">
    <li class="category-name" style="font-weight:600;padding-right:20px;"><a href="">{{category.name}}01</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-collapse88">
    <ul style="padding:0px;">
      {% for forum in category|forumindexlistbycat %}
      <div class="catlistforum">
        <li style="padding-right:10px;"><a href="{{ forum.get_absolute_url }}">{{forum.name}}01</a></li>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul class="catindexlist catlistcat nav-collapse89">
  {% for category in catindexlisted %}
  <div class="catindexlistitem">
    <li class="category-name" style="font-weight:600;padding-right:20px;"><a href="">{{category.name}}02</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-collapse88">
    <ul style="padding:0px;">
      {% for forum in category|forumindexlistbycat %}
      <div class="catlistforum">
        <li style="padding-right:10px;"><a href="{{ forum.get_absolute_url }}">{{forum.name}}02</a></li>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul class="catindexlist catlistcat nav-collapse89">
  {% for category in catindexlisted %}
  <div class="catindexlistitem">
    <li class="category-name" style="font-weight:600;padding-right:20px;"><a href="">{{category.name}}03</a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-collapse88">
    <ul style="padding:0px;">
      {% for forum in category|forumindexlistbycat %}
      <div class="catlistforum">
        <li style="padding-right:10px;"><a href="{{ forum.get_absolute_url }}">{{forum.name}}03</a></li>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Well the snippet seems to work fine but when I try in my project, its hiding all my categories as well and leaving my navbar completely blank. I'm now trying to modify your code.

Comment: Edit your Question and post your Full HTML so that debugging will be more easy I think. Maybe there are DOM issues.